# React somehow makes a request for a second instance of itself through html when I render it

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Sorry it's hard to explain and that's why I'm not sure how to fix it.

I'm trying to do server side rendering with React and to start I removed all client side JS, so it's just CSS and static HTML.

I noticed that when I open localhost, my server reports being triggered twice for root. I checked the network pane of chrome and saw a second row for "localhost" except the second row has type "text/html" instead of document.

My first question is, how is this possible with no JS?

My second question is, how do I stop this?

what chrome network shows (notice second localhost on bottom):

[image: Chrome Network Pane.]

HTML returned by my server: (the super long line are just my articles and wouldn't be the html triggering grabbing a second html document)

```
<html lang="en" data-reactroot="" data-reactid="1" data-react-checksum="1083304721">
    <head data-reactid="2">
        <title data-reactid="3">Jayeh - Jasons tech and opinions</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/base.css" data-reactid="4"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/default.css" data-reactid="5"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" data-reactid="6"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/styles/codepen-embed.css" data-reactid="7"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" data-reactid="8"/>
    </head>
    <body data-reactid="9">
        <div data-reactid="10">
            <span style="font-family:Baskerville;font-size:36px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;border-right:solid 2px grey;border-bottom:solid 2px grey;" data-reactid="11">Blog</span>
            <div style="margin-left:5%;max-width:800px;height:120px;" data-reactid="12"><a class="blackReadable" href="/article/t/${article.title}" data-reactid="13"><div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(&#x27;/dist/header1.jpg&#x27;);background-size:100%;font-family:Open Sans;border:1px dashed maroon;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" data-reactid="14"><p style="font-size:2em;" data-reactid="15">Q Avoiding State on The Web</p><p style="font-size:1em;margin-left:4em;" data-reactid="16">I discuss a saner way to program</p><p style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;" data-reactid="17"><!-- react-text: 18 -->Created On: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 19 -->Thu Feb 18 2016<!-- /react-text --></p></div></a></div><div style="margin-left:5%;max-width:800px;height:120px;" data-reactid="20"><a class="blackReadable" href="/article/t/${article.title}" data-reactid="21"><div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(&#x27;&#x27;);background-size:100%;font-family:Open Sans;border:1px dashed maroon;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" data-reactid="22"><p style="font-size:2em;" data-reactid="23">subarticle</p><p style="font-size:1em;margin-left:4em;" data-reactid="24"></p><p style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;" data-reactid="25"><!-- react-text: 26 -->Created On: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 27 -->Wed Dec 31 1969<!-- /react-text --></p></div></a></div><div style="margin-left:5%;max-width:800px;height:120px;" data-reactid="28"><a class="blackReadable" href="/article/t/${article.title}" data-reactid="29"><div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(&#x27;&#x27;);background-size:100%;font-family:Open Sans;border:1px dashed maroon;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" data-reactid="30"><p style="font-size:2em;" data-reactid="31">blargy</p><p style="font-size:1em;margin-left:4em;" data-reactid="32"></p><p style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;" data-reactid="33"><!-- react-text: 34 -->Created On: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35 -->Thu Feb 18 2016<!-- /react-text --></p></div></a></div><div style="margin-left:5%;max-width:800px;height:120px;" data-reactid="36"><a class="blackReadable" href="/article/t/${article.title}" data-reactid="37"><div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(&#x27;/dist/header2.png&#x27;);background-size:100%;font-family:Open Sans;border:1px dashed maroon;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" data-reactid="38"><p style="font-size:2em;" data-reactid="39">Avoiding State on The Web</p><p style="font-size:1em;margin-left:4em;" data-reactid="40">I discuss saner way to program</p><p style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;" data-reactid="41"><!-- react-text: 42 -->Created On: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 43 -->Invalid Date<!-- /react-text --></p></div></a></div><div style="margin-left:5%;max-width:800px;height:120px;" data-reactid="44"><a class="blackReadable" href="/article/t/${article.title}" data-reactid="45"><div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(&#x27;/dist/header1.png&#x27;);background-size:100%;font-family:Open Sans;border:1px dashed maroon;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" data-reactid="46"><p style="font-size:2em;" data-reactid="47">Avoiding State on The Web</p><p style="font-size:1em;margin-left:4em;" data-reactid="48">I discuss a saner way to program</p><p style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;" data-reactid="49"><!-- react-text: 50 -->Created On: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 51 -->Invalid Date<!-- /react-text --></p></div></a></div><div style="margin-left:5%;max-width:800px;height:120px;" data-reactid="52"><a class="blackReadable" href="/article/t/${article.title}" data-reactid="53"><div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(&#x27;/dist/header1.png&#x27;);background-size:100%;font-family:Open Sans;border:1px dashed maroon;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" data-reactid="54"><p style="font-size:2em;" data-reactid="55">ZZZAvoiding State on The Web</p><p style="font-size:1em;margin-left:4em;" data-reactid="56">I discuss a saner way to program</p><p style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;" data-reactid="57"><!-- react-text: 58 -->Created On: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 59 -->Invalid Date<!-- /react-text --></p></div></a></div><div style="margin-left:5%;max-width:800px;height:120px;" data-reactid="60"><a class="blackReadable" href="/article/t/${article.title}" data-reactid="61"><div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(&#x27;/dist/header1.jpg&#x27;);background-size:100%;font-family:Open Sans;border:1px dashed maroon;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" data-reactid="62"><p style="font-size:2em;" data-reactid="63">Avoiding State on The Web</p><p style="font-size:1em;margin-left:4em;" data-reactid="64">I discuss a saner way to program</p><p style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;" data-reactid="65"><!-- react-text: 66 -->Created On: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 67 -->Invalid Date<!-- /react-text --></p></div></a></div><div style="margin-left:5%;max-width:800px;height:120px;" data-reactid="68"><a class="blackReadable" href="/article/t/${article.title}" data-reactid="69"><div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(&#x27;https://jayehtest.s3.amazonaws.com/Screen Shot 2016-09-15 at 12.32.07 PM.png&#x27;);background-size:100%;font-family:Open Sans;border:1px dashed maroon;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" data-reactid="70"><p style="font-size:2em;" data-reactid="71"> Redux Game Development</p><p style="font-size:1em;margin-left:4em;" data-reactid="72">and how to over complicate physics</p><p style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;" data-reactid="73"><!-- react-text: 74 -->Created On: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 75 -->Sat Sep 17 2016<!-- /react-text --></p></div></a></div>
        </div>
        <p style="margin-top:100px;text-align:right;" data-reactid="76">jayeh.ca © 2016 (Jason McCarrell)</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell without looking at your html source.

Comment: I added the html and a screenshot of the chrome network panel

Comment: This is still open, but it is definitely not blocking me. I've since managed to get my blog to be fully isomorphic in an efficient manner. One extra HTML load isn't going to hurt anything.